# Telegraf unable to pull route table information from Arista MIB

Tags: snmp, telegraf

So I'm trying to collect routing stats from some Aristas.

When I run snmpwalk it all seems to work...

snmpwalk -v2c -c pub router.host ARISTA-FIB-STATS-MIB::aristaFIBStatsTotalRoutesForRouteType
ARISTA-FIB-STATS-MIB::aristaFIBStatsTotalRoutesForRouteType.ipv4.other = Gauge32: 3
ARISTA-FIB-STATS-MIB::aristaFIBStatsTotalRoutesForRouteType.ipv4.connected = Gauge32: 8
ARISTA-FIB-STATS-MIB::aristaFIBStatsTotalRoutesForRouteType.ipv4.static = Gauge32: 26
ARISTA-FIB-STATS-MIB::aristaFIBStatsTotalRoutesForRouteType.ipv4.ospf = Gauge32: 542
ARISTA-FIB-STATS-MIB::aristaFIBStatsTotalRoutesForRouteType.ipv4.bgp = Gauge32: 1623
ARISTA-FIB-STATS-MIB::aristaFIBStatsTotalRoutesForRouteType.ipv4.attached = Gauge32: 12
ARISTA-FIB-STATS-MIB::aristaFIBStatsTotalRoutesForRouteType.ipv4.internal = Gauge32: 25
ARISTA-FIB-STATS-MIB::aristaFIBStatsTotalRoutesForRouteType.ipv6.other = Gauge32: 3
ARISTA-FIB-STATS-MIB::aristaFIBStatsTotalRoutesForRouteType.ipv6.internal = Gauge32: 1

But when I try to pull the stats with telegraf I get different information with missing context...

> BGP,agent_host=10.45.100.20,host=nw01.ny5,hostname=CR.NY aristaFIBStatsTotalRoutesForRouteType=2i 1654976575000000000
> BGP,agent_host=10.45.100.20,host=nw01.ny5,hostname=CR.NY aristaFIBStatsTotalRoutes=2260i 1654976575000000000
> BGP,agent_host=10.45.100.20,host=nw01.ny5,hostname=CR.NY aristaFIBStatsTotalRoutesForRouteType=8i 1654976575000000000
> BGP,agent_host=10.45.100.20,host=nw01.ny5,hostname=CR.NY aristaFIBStatsTotalRoutesForRouteType=63i 1654976575000000000

According to the MIB documentation..

https://www.arista.com/assets/data/docs/MIBS/ARISTA-FIB-STATS-MIB.txt

it is using IANA-RTPROTO-MIB.txt protocol definitions but I have no idea where to derive that information from as the retrieved data via telegraf isn't showing me anything.  Anyone know how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

First, you might want to enable telegraf to return the index of the returned rows by setting `index_as_tag = true` inside the `inputs.snmp.table`.

Then, add the following processors in your config:

```toml
# Parse aristaFIBStatsAF and aristaFIBStatsRouteType from index for BGP table
[[processors.regex]]
  namepass = ["BGP"]
  order = 1

  [[processors.regex.tags]]
    ## Tag to change
    key = "index"
    ## Regular expression to match on a tag value
    pattern = "^(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)$"
    replacement = "${1}"
    ## Tag to store the result
    result_key = "aristaFIBStatsAF"

  [[processors.regex.tags]]
    ## Tag to change
    key = "index"
    ## Regular expression to match on a tag value
    pattern = "^(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)$"
    replacement = "${2}"
    ## Tag to store the result
    result_key = "aristaFIBStatsRouteType"


# Rename index to aristaFIBStatsAF for BGP table with single index row
[[processors.rename]]
  namepass = ["BGP"]
  order = 2

  [[processors.rename.replace]]
    tag = "index"
    dest = "aristaFIBStatsAF"

  [processors.rename.tagdrop]
    aristaFIBStatsAF = ["*"]


# Translate tag values for BGP table
[[processors.enum]]
  namepass = ["BGP"]
  order = 3
  tagexclude = ["index"]

  [[processors.enum.mapping]]
    ## Name of the tag to map
    tag = "aristaFIBStatsAF"

    ## Table of mappings
    [processors.enum.mapping.value_mappings]
      0 = "unknown"
      1 = "ipv4"
      2 = "ipv6"

  [[processors.enum.mapping]]
    ## Name of the tag to map
    tag = "aristaFIBStatsRouteType"

    ## Table of mappings
    [processors.enum.mapping.value_mappings]
      1   = "other"
      2   = "connected"
      3   = "static"
      8   = "rip"
      9   = "isIs"
      13  = "ospf"
      14  = "bgp"
      200 = "ospfv3"
      201 = "staticNonPersistent"
      202 = "staticNexthopGroup"
      203 = "attached"
      204 = "vcs"
      205 = "internal"
```

Disclaimer: did not test this in telegraf, so there might be some typo's